# Unidirectional editings

Tags: discussion, moderators

I posted [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13245/an-infallible-cannot-commit-sin-but-can-he-make-a-mistake/13354#13354) sometimes ago, and I saw that it was edited by goldPseudo♦. I had explicitly mentioned that a hadith was narrated by Shia scholars and some Sunni scholars. I had mentioned the reference by which one could find the narration in Sunni books. To my surprise, the Mod had omitted the references and the term showing that the hadith was narrated in Sunni references.

Can any one tell me the reasoning behind his unidirectional edits?

By the way, there are some comments under the answer which may help you understand how we got to this point.

Comment: If you'd actually *read* the comments under your answer, you'd know you were already linked to the meta discussion explaining exactly the reasoning behind the edits.

Comment: @goldPseudo every time you refer us to your wall of texts! could you please be brief?

Comment: My comment of "Explicitly calling out Sunni sources to prove a Shi'ite perspective is a tactic used by polemic sites, and has no place here." wasn't brief enough?  What exactly are you having trouble understanding here?

Comment: @MohammadHossein That "wall of texts" is meant to be read, and the community has pains takenly brought them forward and discussed them. And we value it. And these topics have to be in detail to explain the rationale. Please take the time to go through them and if you don't agree you're welcome to propose something else.